# Openshift or Kubernate environment variables from file

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to know if there is anyway to define the kubernate or openshift template to load environment variables from a file in one of the volumes.

What i'm trying to achieve is to:

- generate a value on a initContainer
- write value on a file
- load value as an environment variable when starting the main container

If anyone knows an alternative to allow the main container to read a environment variable generated from the initContainer it will solve my problem too

Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have a initConteiner that generates a value, and a container that only accepts inputs from environment variables. I have control only on the initContainer and the deployment template

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways to reach what you need:

**1 - Use configMap:**  You need to give permissions to your initContainer runs `kubectl` to create a `configmap` or `secret` with the desired value and make your main container read the configmap and configure as environment variable.

**2 - Use persistentVolume:** In the initContainer to write the file, and them mount the same volume on the pod, read the file and use as you want.

The **first** method is much more *elegant* IMO because you can configure the permission level and isolate the configMap object for using the Role permissions.

The **second** method is easier and requires less steps than the second, **but** it depends what kind of data you need to store, if it is a **sensible data**, I would recommend go to second method.

## METHOD 1

This way consists in create a kubernetes `configMap` with the variable you wish and use the value from this configMap to configure a environment variable in main container.

It requires some extra steps:

- Create a serviceAccount
- Create a Role allowing the serviceAccount perfom action in the configmap
- Create a RoleBinding to connect the serviceAccount with the Role

In this case the `initContainer` will be the responsible to create/update the `configmap`, and your main container will read this configmap and configure the values as env vars.

> **NOTE**: In this examples I'm using all resource in **myns** namespace.
> You should make the proper changes to best fit in you environment such as: Role/ClusterRole permissions, you could make ir more restrictive using `resourceNames`. See here

`envFrom`: This will be the responsible to read the configMap from Kubernetes and set you environment variable. More information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

RBAC

The following spec will create the [`serviceAccount`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/), [`Role` and `RoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole):

Create a file named `rbac-sa-myuser.yaml` with the following content

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-myuser
  namespace: myns
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: myns
  name: role-configmap
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["create", "update", "get", "patch", "delete"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rolebinding-configmap
  namespace: myns
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: role-configmap
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-myuser
  namespace: myns
```

Apply with `kubectl apply -f rbac-sa-myuser.yaml`

Now, you need to make the proper changes in you deployment template, adding the extra parameters:

**serviceAccountName:**

```yaml
 spec:
   serviceAccountName: sa-myuser
```

**envFrom:**

```yaml
envFrom:
  - configMapRef:
      name: my-var
```

**initContainer:** Here is just an example of a initContainer running a command to create the configMap, you need to adjust for your use case:

```yaml
 initContainers:
   - name: my-init
     image: bitnami/kubectl
     command: ['sh', '-c', 'kubectl delete cm my-var ; kubectl create cm my-var --from-literal MYVAR=UPVOTEIT']
```

In the end, your deployment spec must looks likes the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: var-example
  namespace: myns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: var-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: var-example
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sa-myuser
      containers:
      - name: var-example
        image: nginx
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: my-var
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
      initContainers:
        - name: my-init
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'kubectl delete cm my-var ; kubectl create cm my-var --from-literal MYVAR=UPVOTEIT']
```

#### Method 2: persistentVolume

You will need to create a persistVolume and mount in both pods, as an example, I will use [**hostPath**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) to demonstrate how it works, but you need to find the best kind of persistent volume for your workload. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes) a list of all kinds.

The follow `yaml` will create a 2Gi persistentVolume and a persistentVolumeClaim of 1Gi on your node.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Then just create your deployment mounting the volume in the initContainer and the main pod, example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: var-example
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: var-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: var-example
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: var-example
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
            name: pv-storage
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo MYVAR=$(cat /mnt/data/myfile.txt) >> /etc/environment ; sleep 3600"]
      initContainers:
        - name: my-init
          image: busybox:1.28
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
              name: pv-storage
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo "UPVOTE_IT" > /mnt/data/myfile.txt']
```