# How can I use the dynamic output of a Kubernetes resource as the environment variable in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a custom resource in Kubernetes that outputs some dynamic properties in the status:

```
status:
  outputs:
    BasicParameter: command-k8s-test
```

I would like to be able to use that output value as an environment variable in a pod.  Is there any way to do this?  Via direct reference, or via an init container, or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native feature for that, but you can use a workaround that will works.

For example, if your application requires the value of `output` field, you can add a `initContainer` to get this value and generate a kubernetes `configMap`. Then, in you container you can use the value of the config map as a environment variable.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375369/openshift-or-kubernate-environment-variables-from-file/63070919#63070919) you can find how to make your init container create a configMap, and then use this value as a environment variable.