# How to export environment variable by the start up script of the pod

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes, environment-variables

I am trying to create the environment variable using the startup script inside the initcontainer of the pod like below

```
 initContainers:
   - name: init-myservice
     image: ubuntu
     command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
     args: [". /a/b/Exporter.sh"]
```

and Exporter.sh script has the below line in it

```
export JOBID=$temp
```

But when script is executed successfully and I go and check for the environment variable exported by the script in another pod, environment variable is not present in another pod. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Makes sense, right? It's an _environment_ variable, and the different container does not share this environment. You can consider something like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/).

Comment: I'd try to do something like this in an entrypoint wrapper script in my image, rather than a separate container.

Comment: I have shared the value using shared volume. But I am unable to set that to a pod environment variable. How to do it? I am trying like this export COUCHBASEJOB_ID=$(echo $line) . But this is not changing the env variable  COUCHBASEJOB_ID

Comment: Could you try to check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070919/11977760)  answer your question? There is an example with configmap and shared volume.